# Get user's posts with the posts of the user's friends

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get posts of the current user's friends from the the `posts` table , What I've tried is this code :

```
SELECT 
    `p`.id,
    `p`.thetext,
    `p`.time,
    `p`.location
FROM 
    `friends` as f,
    `users` as u,
    `posts` as p
WHERE 
    `f`.frid = `u`.id
AND 
    `p`.publisher = `u`.username
AND 
    `f`.username = '$userusername'
ORDER BY 
    `p`.orderdate DESC
```

This code is getting the user's friends' posts but I want to show the the posts of the user and the posts of the user's friends (with the ordering).

What to do please ?

Comment: Well... it looks like you need to work on understanding the database schema and SQL. You should do this now when the things are relatively simple and easy to understand. Please do not skip this learning by asking on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your advising but can you answer to my question , please ?

Comment: can you mention your all tables used in query?

Comment: @Sarihny-Website that is the issue here. You should not be asking this on SO and neither should anyone try to answer this here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/nLoMMhE | http://imgur.com/8WGOA8Q | http://imgur.com/npLSKdu

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Yeah... tahts the big problem here on SO. There are many questions which shouldn't be answered (for example all these mysql_ questions.. why answer questions where people are using a technologie thats completly outdated and unsafe..?) are answered anyways.. because often these questions are easy to answer and people want reputation... thats a big problem x:

Comment: @Twinfriends mysql is unsafe ?! you mean it can be hacked or what ?

Comment: @Sarihny-Website I'm talking about the `mysql_` functions from PHP. They're deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. We should use `mysqli_` or `PDO_` to query the database. Sadly, a lot of people still use the old `mysql_` extensions what leads to code with deprecated technologie. Here on SO still a lot of people ask question and post code with this old extension, and here are still a lot of people supporting them by provoding answers, instead of telling them to switch to another SQL driver and then ask again. I personally have stopped supporting these people and I don't answer them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    `p`.id,
    `p`.thetext,
    `p`.time,
    `p`.location
FROM `posts` as p
INNER JOIN  `users` as u ON `p`.publisher = `u`.username
LEFT JOIN `friends` as f ON `f`.frid = `u`.id
WHERE 
    `f`.username = '$userusername'
ORDER BY 
    `p`.orderdate DESC
```

Please try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: This query gets me nothing

Comment: Are you sure every user who made a post had entry in `posts` and `users` table and ``p`.publisher = `u`.username` will always return true.

Comment: No, maybe the user didn't publish a post yet ! that's mean the user could be have no posts

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    `p`.id,
    `p`.thetext,
    `p`.time,
    `p`.location
FROM 
    `friends` as f,
    `users` as u,
    `posts` as p
WHERE 
    `f`.frid = `u`.id 
AND 
   ( `p`.publisher = `u`.username or `p`.publisher = '$userusername')
AND 
    `f`.username = '$userusername'
ORDER BY 
    `p`.orderdate DESC
```

Comment: Distinct the post id then try again `SELECT 
    distinct(`p`.id),
    `p`.thetext,
    `p`.time,
    `p`.location
FROM `